# ConcatenatingAudioSource in Just_audio loads continuously nonstop and crashed the app

Tags: flutter, just-audio

I use the concatenatingaudiosource to load gapless music this way:

```
ConcatenatingAudioSource(
                children: _mediaItems
                    .map((item) => AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(item.id)))
                    .toList(),
              ),
              initialIndex: startIndex,
              initialPosition: pos >= _mediaItems[startIndex].duration
                  ? Duration(seconds: 0)
                  : pos);
```

This methods works fine all along until it started crashing recently. It will load continuously with the following flutter output:

`flutter: Warning database has been locked for 0:00:10.000000. Make sure you always use the transaction object for database operations during a transaction`

and make the whole app ui unresponsive.

I noticed that the loading time reduces if I reduce the playlist to about 4-5 songs, which is very small compared to what we use in production(80-100 songs before and it worked fast and fine).

I will be glad if anyone can help out.

Comment: That warning looks like it's coming from sqflite. Maybe your database code is responsible?

Comment: @RyanHeise We don't use sqlite in the project. This only occurs when just_audio is loading the playlist.

Comment: Probably sqflite is transitively included by another one of your dependencies, even though you haven't explicitly included it as a dependency. Checking `pubspec.lock` will confirm.

Comment: You are right. Sqflite is transitevely included. We use just_audio for the player and audio_service for the background handling. This issue wasn't present before and started occuring only recently. I believe it is linked with just audio because it only happens when the player is loading audiosource. What do you think I can do? @RyanHeise

Comment: You could try disabling the code that depends on sqflite to rule that out first.

Comment: How do I do that? I noticed that it doesn't happen when i set the preload to false on the ContatenatingAudioSource, and it appears again whenever I call the the load() on the player at some other time in the app. Can this be linked to thr just_audio packages? Please help me out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237981/discussion-between-ryan-heise-and-intellect).